# Use WinJS to bind attributes of HTML element and how to prevent knockout from binding on HTML elements ?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, winjs

I know they`re two separated questions but : 
Is there is any way to use WinJS to Bind on attributes of an element such as ( ID , name ) .

Unfortunately I've to use Knockout data-bind (to bind on attributes ) with Winjs-data-bind (to bind on html elements ) . so is there is a way to control Knockout  binding in order to prevent elements binding and allow just Attributes binding .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html - in Knockout you can create some custom binding that will stop KO from binding child elements of other HTML element. Then you can run `WinJS.Binding.processAll` on all child elements and it won't interfere with KO bindings.

Comment: thanks alot mjzer , that`s what i was asking about .